# Cannot display data from ClearDB MySQL through Flask in React

Tags: mysql, reactjs, flask, cleardb

I am using Heroku's add-on ClearDB MySQL to manage database, Python Flask for backend, and React for frontend.

I successfully setup the database through MySQL Workbench and connected it to the backend like that:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
  host = 'host-here',
  user = 'user-here',
  password = 'password-here',
  database = 'db-here',
  port = '3306'

)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

I also created a table `individual` with a sample row data through MySQL Workbench and made the following endpoint to just select all the data from the table:

```
@app.route('/api1/create', methods=['GET'])
def get_person():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM individual")
    row_headers = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    json_data = []
    for result in data:
      json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))
    return json.dumps(json_data)
```

For the frontend, I'm using hooks to get data from the database:

```
const [dataDB, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  const getData = async() => {
    const result = await axios (`/api1/create`, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log("getData: " + result);
    setData(result);
  };

return (
   <table className="result_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Info</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       {dataDB ?
         dataDB.map((item, idx) => (
         <tr key={idx}>
           <td>{item.individual_id}</td>
           <td>{item.first_name}</td>
           <td>{item.last_name}</td>
           <td>{item.info}</td>
           <td>{item.gender}</td>
         </tr>
       ))
       : <p>Can't get data</p>
     }
       </tbody>
      </table>
)
```

This is supposed to return the table with that sample data I inserted into the `individual table` through MySQL Workbench.

However, when I deploy the apps on Heroku, I am able to get db data on my backend but I lose it once I open a page on React frontend.

Meaning that when I open `https://mybackend.herokuapp.com/api1/create`, I see the json data, but when I open `https://myfrontend.herokuapp.com/create` (the route is /create but, remember, in the hooks above I am calling useEffect and getData with endpoint /api1/create to fetch data) at the same time, the data on the backend get lost after page refresh and throw an error.

Frontend just shows "Can't get data", meaning that dataDB state has never been updated.

Not sure what's wrong... Here are the errors I get in the log.

Frontend:

```
 at=info method=GET path="/api1/create" ... status=404 protocol=https
```

Backend:

```
: at=info method=GET path="/create" ....connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 protocol=http
```

Is there anything I am missing?

P.S. I am using `api1/...` because there is another backend handling other feature, so I distinguish them as `api1` and `api2` respectively in the setupProxy.js.

Comment: It seems like your backend path is `/api1/create`, but the actual request going to the backend is `/create`. Which is a 404.

Comment: You have to show setupProxy